# How to echo an exclamation point without the backslash in the output to prevent expansion

Tags: bash, echo

I usually like to `echo` certain string which have an exclamation point in them. And while i [know](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154118/echo-of-a-string-with-an-exclamation-point) how to escape them to prevent expansion by the Shell, i noticed it *also* print the backslash...

```bsh
echo "\!" # will print \! instead of just !
```

Contrary to other tool like `sed` which *does not* print the backslash if used to prevent expansion of possible valid parameter used by `sed`:

```bsh
echo "test" | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\1 \!/' # print -> test !
echo "test" | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\1 !/' # also print -> test !
echo "test" | sed "s/^\(.*\)$/\1 ! /" # also print -> test !, though needed to put a space or use a backslash for it to show correctly
```

How can i do the same with `echo` or I'm i obliged to use other tools like `sed`?

EDIT:

Just noticed using `''` instead of `""` with the `echo` example above works for printing `!` without shell expansion (both with and without the backslash), though:

- It wouldn't work in instance when one want to use command substitution with `echo`, since it only work with `""`...

Comment: Related: [Can't use exclamation mark (!) in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33339/170373). Btw, I'm of the opinion that history expansion should just be disabled by default (`set +H`).

Comment: [Don't use `echo` for anything that may contain backslashes or may start with `-`](/q/65803).

Comment: Didn't thought of disabling history expansion, good idea! (especially since i never use it afaik). @ilkkachu

Comment: That post's accepted answer have some nice alternative to `echo`, Thanks! @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: See also: [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape it *or* quote it, not both:

```
echo \!
echo "!"
```

Bash history expansion ignores escaped exclamation marks, single-quoted exclamation marks, and exclamation marks which appear just before a closing double quote. See [the History Interaction section of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) for details. So

```
echo '!'
```

also works, and without having to think about where the exclamation mark is.

You can combine single quotes with variable expansion by using `printf` instead of `echo`. You can also combine multiple forms of quoting in the same command-line:

```
echo '!'"$(echo test)"
```

In general though, [`printf` is better than `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/86440). As others have mentioned you can also disable history expansion entirely; non-interactive shells don’t enable it by default.

Comment: Using `echo "!"` works yes, but it usually *won't* if used with command substitution, like so: `echo "!$(echo "test")"` (although it's probably because of the `$` character). Any way around it?

Comment: OH, didn't thought of using `printf` like this! Guess that works with `echo` too: `echo "$(echo "test")""!"` yep, works! Thanks for the idea

Comment: FYI, i used the term `usually` loosely. eg: `this doesn't work, unless you do X Y Z which i don't know/didn't thought about`.

Comment: Or escape with single quotes. Which is the better way anyway, if you need something like `foo!bar`, or whatever where the `!` isn't in one of the positions that don't trigger history expansion

Comment: How safe it is to use `!` inside double quotes and in which condition depends on the version of bash.

Comment: also `echo "!"` doesn't really seem to work in Zsh. Or Ksh.

Comment: @ilkkachu, which ksh would that be? I'm not aware of any ksh implementation that implemented csh history expansion (and zsh disables banghist when in ksh emulation)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, whatever the one on Debian and Ubuntu is.

Comment: @ilkkachu, there are several implementations of ksh available on Debian/Ubuntu. mksh and ksh93 or ksh2020 depending on the version. ksh2020 has been abandoned so Debian is going back to ksh93 IIRC. In any case `echo "!"` outputs `!` in all the ones I've tried here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, this: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/ksh and this: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ksh It's mentioned also here: https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/cmd/ksh93/RELEASE#L1827

Comment: @ilkkachu, but yes, you're right, it seems ksh93 implemented csh-style history expansion in ksh93r, though I find it's not enabled by default here and it's not documented in the Debian man page (though it is in `ksh --man`). TIL

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yes, you're right, I had to manually enable it. Didn't think too much of that, since I have it disabled and have to manually enable it anyway...